# Reset cursor to windows default

Tags: phpstorm

I recently switched to PhpStorm and somehow the cursor is similar to [image: this]. I am not sure where to reset it to windows default that is displayed like a `|` line rather than a vertical rectangle. If I turn `Insert` on, the cursor is displayed as normal but then the Insert is on so that doesn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"then the Insert is on so that doesn't work either."*? On Windows, most text editors support both "insert" and "overwrite" mode. On the "insert" mode the caret is a vertical line; on the "overwrite" mode it is a block like the one you displayed in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, most text editors support both "insert" and "overwrite" mode.

On the "insert" mode the caret is a vertical line and the characters you type are inserted at the caret position. On the "overwrite" mode, the caret is a block and the characters you type replace the characters at the cursor position.

You can switch between the two editing modes using the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. The "insert" mode is the default.

PhpStorm can display a block caret in the "insert" mode. To enable this open application Settings then under `Editor`/`General`/`Appearance` check `Use block caret`.

I don't have a Windows computer at hand, I cannot tell if PhpStorm displays a line caret in the "overwrite" mode when the `Use block caret` is checked. :-(

Comment: It worked nice in the Appearance option in Settings, thanks.for the quick response. Insert works as it should as well after this.